# Keep browser open for all tests in a test suite

Tags: playwright

The typical structure of my tests is as follows:

```js
import {test} from '@playwright/test';

test.describe('suite', () => {
   test('test1', async ({page}) => {
      await page.goto('test1');
   }); 
   test('test2', async ({page}) => {
      await page.goto('test2');
   }); 
});
```

This works perfectly but I noticed that Playwright opens and closes the browser window for each test and was wondering, why the browser window cannot stay open for all tests and if this could/should be optimised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my feedback from a playwright contributor:

- If you use the VSCode extension, the browser stays open: https://playwright.dev/docs/getting-started-vscode
- You want to ensure full test isolation on your CI, what Playwright does it guarantees that so no test will infer with each other. (less reasons to flake)

Comment: It’s definitely because each test runs in its own context, so is on purpose. But if this answer answered your question, don’t forget that you can come back and mark your answer as accepted to quickly indicate to others finding this question that your problem was indeed solved!